# Package is installed and is not detected. (gradle)

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, reset, purge, gradle

I installed gradle by typical way:

```
sudo apt install gradle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gradle is already the newest version (3.5-0ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
```

Next I wanted to use this program:

```
$ gradle 
The program 'gradle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install gradle
```

I was trying to remove java, purge gradle, remove it from anywhere and install again. Nothing helps... The most confusing is that this package was working correctly some days earlier without troubles.

Below some debug:

```
$ which gradle
$ whereis gradle
gradle:
$ apt-cache policy gradle
gradle:
  Installed: 3.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cwchien/gradle/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cwchien/gradle/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.10-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
     1.4-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe i386 Packages
```

How to revert system to state, when this package will be correctly detected?

#### Update

I found command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Now i obtain:

```
sudo apt install gradle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gradle is already the newest version (3.5-0ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pl) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
```

#### Update2

```
dpkg -L gradle
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gradle
/usr/share/doc/gradle/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gradle/copyright

namei -lx /usr/bin/gradle
f: /usr/bin/gradle
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root bin
                     gradle - No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try reinstalling it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gradle`

Comment: Unfortunately the same effect.

Comment: Add the output of `dpkg -L gradle` and `namei -lx /usr/bin/gradle`, please.

Comment: So whichever PPA you're using for gradle doesn't provide the binary in the `gradle` package. It seems they have a separate `gradle-3.5` package.

Comment: So... What should I do?

Comment: I obtained: `gradle-3.5 is already the newest version (1.0-0ubuntu1).` and `gradle` still not works. Maybe it help that I have second computer, that has correct settings and on this gradle working correctly.

Comment: Then I suggest asking whoever made the PPA.

Comment: ppa:cwchien/gradle, anyway thank you very much!

Comment: You can place your suggestion into answer, so I would like to confirm it as correct solution of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally thanks to comments of @muru I done the following steps:

I removed `ppa:cwchien/gradle`:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cwchien-ubuntu-gradle-xenial.*
sudo apt-get update
```

I installed old gradle from official repo:

```
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

Then all dependencies was installed correctly. Then I append `cwchien-ubuntu-gradle-xenial` again and installed again:

```
sudo apt-get install gradle-ppa gradle
```

Finally in website https://gradle.org/install I found command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-3.5/bin
```

That finally solved my problems, and now:

```
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.5
------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Update

Now I installing gradle by [sdkman.io](http://sdkman.io/) by these commands:

Install sdkman

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Install gradle

```
sdk install gradle 4.0.2
```